# Getting error while using getHibernateTemplate().persist()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've got the following error while using getHibernateTemplate().persist() method in hql

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist:
```

Is there any way to fix this ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does your entity have fields that are themselves entities?

Comment: @lechlukasz THanks for your reply . I fixedt it by using merge() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to persist ("first time save") an existing entity (i.e. with an id greater than 0, if it's numerical).
Try merge or saveOrUpdate instead.